# Unable to execute command from Jenkins User in linux node

Tags: linux, jenkins

I installed Fortify software in Linux using the user "US-KIRAN". When I typed "sourceanalyzer --v" using the user "Kiran" I got "Fortify Static Code Analyzer 19.2.0.0196 (using JRE 1.8.0_181)" in linux.

But when I executed same command from Jenkins user "US-JENKINS" I am getting command not found. sourceanalyzer --v bash: sourceanalyzer: command not found

Can someone please help me how to make the command work from Jenkins user.

Comment: `sourceanalyzer` needs to be in the `PATH` of the user `US-JENKINS`, run `echo $PATH` to see the `PATH`.

Comment: Or specify the full path to binary.

Comment: @root thanks for your reply. I cant install software in the PATH of the user US-JENKINS due to space constraints. I can install the software in /opt only. Please let me know how to execute the command from Jenkins user.

Comment: You can just change the `PATH` variable (`export PATH=$PATH:/my/directory), or just use the full path to `sourceanalyzer` (`/my/directory/sourceanalyzer --v`).

Comment: @root: Awesome it worked thanks. 
``` node('vanguard')
{ stage('Build') 
    { sh '''cd /opt/Fortify/bin 
    PATH=$PATH:/opt/Fortify/bin 
    sourceanalyzer --version ''' } } 
```